# Free tutorial websites for VBA version 7 for Office Excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

What are the **FREE** websites for VBA version 7 for Office 2007?

Google lets us down with  a lot of payed spam with "the best of the best of the best" tutorials EVER.

I have the experience with programming from C#, .NET, Object Pascal, PHP,.. It will not be for a beginner, rather the intermediate in the field. Explaining what Hello World is not necessary; I don't mind to go through that if the Tuts are really good in the end..

Please, advise.

For flamers: we all know what "free" would mean to google and websites (demos...)

Comment: sometimes you get what you pay for.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the best tutor in VBA is practice!  With experience of the languages mentioned you will have a reasonable base programming knowledge.  Learning VBA for Office is mostly about getting to grips with the Office Object Model.

1. use the macro recorder
2. study the object model
3. think laterally (I must confess, the object model doesn't always make sense, but it does usually work!)
4. note the use of the word 'usually'
5. try solving real problems
6. when in doubt, search SO

Comment: nice answer, pretty much covers everything you need. I think possibly the questioner may have been asking specifcally about the few minor changes from VBA 6 to VBA 7, however i might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've just completed a comprehensive free online tutorial at [enter link description here](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s161/online-excel-vba-training.htm).  It starts with the basics, but you can choose where you join in (so you'll find everything from recording macros through to creating classes).  It's based on nearly 20 years of experience of running training classes in Excel VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good tutorial [here](http://www.functionx.com/vbaexcel/).

Its was good enough to get started on Excel VBA.

And as chris neilsen said, macro recorder is quite helpful...especially if you want to use one of those nifty functions(e.g. text to columns or remove duplicate entries) via macros.