# Excel VBA create row

Tags: excel, replace, vba

If this is a cell:

```
    Hello; Goodbye
```

..And there are hundreds of cells, I need to do a "find and replace" of all cells containing a ";" and break the cell at that point and moving what is after to a newly inserted row below:

```
   Hello;
   Goodbye
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not optimized for speed but this will do it for you. Make sure you mark it as the correct answer if you think it is.

```
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
Dim saItem() As String


For Each r1 In ActiveSheet.Range("A1", Cells(Application.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
    If InStr(1, r1.Value2, ";") > 0 Then
        saItem = Split(r1.Value2, ";")
        r1 = Trim$(saItem(0)) & ";"
        r1.Offset(1).Insert (xlDown)
        r1.Offset(1) = Trim$(saItem(1))
    End If
Next r1
```

For adding a whole new row instead of

```
r1.Offset(1).Insert (xlDown)
```

do this (not tested, but I'm pretty sure it should work correctly):

```
r1.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert (xlDown)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am very unfamiliar with VB. Will I simply need to create a macro, edit it and insert this code?

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930142/free-tutorial-websites-for-vba-version-7-for-office-excel-2007

Comment: A quick follow up question! This works great when I make a few small changes, however right now it only adds a new cell in that particular column, but idealy I would have it create a new row entirley. Does that make sense?

So if column A had some categories (math, science, english..(a1, a2, a3)) and then column B had (math01;math03, sci01;sci02) and so on, I would want to make the string split at the ; still but also create a blank cell beneath the math category to keep it uniform.. does this make sense?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been looking to see if I got any responses. Thanks for marking my answer as correct. I'll update the answer with an option to create a whole new row.

Comment: Awesome! Again works great!... I am wondering also if it would be possible to do this for a cell that contained more than one ";" ... (hello;goodbye;hi;bye;peaceout)